# Openpyxl - how to loop through pandas data frames and export them into separate worksheets in one file?

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

How to get separate data frames to be exported into separate worksheets in one file?
When following the code below, the output file contains only the last worksheet - `sheet3` despite the mode being `a` as for append.
Fyi: The code works well without looping through the data and assigning and exporting the data frames.

```
import itertools
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd

cnxn = mysql.connector.connect(host=ip_mysql,database = db_mysql,user=user_mysql,password=pswd_mysql)
this_excel = r'C:\excelfile.xlsx'

df = {}

for i, field, table, sheetname  in zip(list(range(1,3)),
    list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat('USER', 1) for x in range(0,2))),
    ['a','b','c'],
    ['sheet1','sheet2','sheet3'],
    ):
    
    df[i] = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT " + field + " FROM " + table, cnxn)
    print(df[i])

    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    wb.save(this_excel)

    with pd.ExcelWriter(this_excel, mode='a') as writer:  
        df[i].to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheetname, index = False)

cnxn.close()
```

Comment: You're creating a new workbook in every step of the loop…

Comment: That I understand. But the questions is - how to prevent it?